# How to access Kafka bridge

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I am using strimzi and I want to learn how to use Kafka bridge and to understand it's working I created a Kafka cluster using following yml file

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1

kind: Kafka

metadata:

  name: my-cluster

spec:

  kafka:

    version: 2.6.0

    replicas: 3

    listeners:

      - name: plain

        port: 9092

        type: internal

        tls: false

      - name: tls

        port: 9093

        type: internal

        tls: true

    config:

      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3

      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3

      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2

      log.message.format.version: "2.6"

    storage:

      type: jbod

      volumes:

      - id: 0

        type: persistent-claim

        size: 100Gi

        deleteClaim: false

  zookeeper:

    replicas: 3

    storage:

      type: persistent-claim

      size: 100Gi

      deleteClaim: false

  entityOperator:

    topicOperator: {}

    userOperator: {}
```

And here is the yml syntax for Kafka bridge

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1

kind: KafkaBridge

metadata:

  name: my-bridge

spec:

  replicas: 1

  bootstrapServers: my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092

  http:

    port: 8080
```

Now here is the services

```
ist@ist-1207:~$ kubectl   get svc -A

NAMESPACE     NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE

default       kubernetes                       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      3d1h

kube-system   kube-dns                         ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       3d1h

strimzi       my-bridge-bridge-service         ClusterIP   10.100.153.164   <none>        8080/TCP                     88m

strimzi       my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap       ClusterIP   10.97.160.117    <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   109m

strimzi       my-cluster-kafka-brokers         ClusterIP   None             <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   109m

strimzi       my-cluster-zookeeper-client      ClusterIP   10.107.59.225    <none>        2181/TCP                     110m

strimzi       my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes       ClusterIP   None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   110m

strimzi       my-connect-cluster-connect-api   ClusterIP   10.110.27.15     <none>        8083/TCP                     25m
```

Now I exec it's pod using following command:

```
$ kubectl  exec -it my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-bktc4 -n strimzi bash
```

And after that

```
[strimzi@my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-bktc4 strimzi]$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/consumers/my-group   -H 'content-type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json'   -d '{
    "name": "your-consumer",
    "format": "json",
    "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
    "enable.auto.commit": false
}'
{"instance_id":"your-consumer","base_uri":"http://localhost:8080/consumers/my-group/instances/your-consumer"}
```

then

```
[strimzi@my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-bktc4 strimzi]$   curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/consumers/my-group/instances/your-consumer/subscription   -H 'content-type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json'   -d '{
    "topics": [
        "your-topic"
    ]
}'
```

then

```
[strimzi@my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-bktc4 strimzi]$   curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/consumers/my-group/instances/your-consumer/records \
>   -H 'accept: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json'
[]
```

then I produced

```
[strimzi@my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-bktc4 strimzi]$ curl -X POST \
>   http://localhost:8080/topics/your-topic \
>   -H 'content-type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json' \
>   -d '{
>     "records": [
>         {
>             "key": "key-1",
>             "value": "kajal verma"
>         },
>         {
>             "key": "key-2",
>             "value": "Aman verma"
>         }
>     ]
> }'
{"offsets":[{"partition":0,"offset":2},{"partition":0,"offset":3}]}


[strimzi@my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-bktc4 strimzi]$   curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/consumers/my-group/instances/your-consumer/records \
>   -H 'accept: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json'
[]
```

again I m not getting the records dont know why.

these are logs for pod bridge

```
ist@ist-1207:~$ kubectl logs -f my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-lstx2 -n strimzi
Kafka Bridge configuration:
#Bridge configuration
bridge.id=my-bridge

#Kafka common properties
kafka.bootstrap.servers=my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
kafka.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT

#Apache Kafka Producer

#Apache Kafka Consumer

#HTTP configuration
http.enabled=true
http.host=0.0.0.0
http.port=8080
http.cors.enabled=false
http.cors.allowedOrigins=
http.cors.allowedMethods=

[2020-11-24 11:42:01,374] INFO  <Application :64> [main        ] Strimzi Kafka Bridge 0.19.0 is starting
[2020-11-24 11:42:02,939] WARN  <onMetaSchema:337> [oop-thread-1] Unknown keyword example - you should define your own Meta Schema. If the keyword is irrelevant for validation, just use a NonValidationKeyword
[2020-11-24 11:42:03,402] INFO  <HttpBridge  :180> [oop-thread-1] Starting HTTP-Kafka bridge verticle...
[2020-11-24 11:42:03,459] INFO  <ClientConfig:354> [oop-thread-1] AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092]
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS

[2020-11-24 11:42:04,336] INFO  <ppInfoParser:117> [oop-thread-1] Kafka version: 2.6.0
[2020-11-24 11:42:04,336] INFO  <ppInfoParser:118> [oop-thread-1] Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
[2020-11-24 11:42:04,338] INFO  <ppInfoParser:119> [oop-thread-1] Kafka startTimeMs: 1606218124265
Nov 24, 2020 11:42:05 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main]=Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 2656 ms, time limit is 2000 ms
Nov 24, 2020 11:42:06 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main]=Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 3869 ms, time limit is 2000 ms
[2020-11-24 11:42:07,589] INFO  <HttpBridge  :102> [oop-thread-1] HTTP-Kafka Bridge started and listening on port 8080
[2020-11-24 11:42:07,604] INFO  <HttpBridge  :103> [oop-thread-1] HTTP-Kafka Bridge bootstrap servers my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
[2020-11-24 11:42:07,609] INFO  <Application :219> [oop-thread-0] HTTP verticle instance deployed [6bc2ded6-162c-4444-b8ac-f51c0573e389]
[2020-11-24 11:44:15,295] WARN  <etworkClient:757> [dminclient-1] [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap/10.97.102.188:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[2020-11-24 11:44:15,301] INFO  <adataManager:235> [dminclient-1] [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1606218154377, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1606218255400) timed out at 1606218255300 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
[2020-11-24 11:46:09,397] INFO  <eateConsumer:85> [oop-thread-1] [9562016] CREATE_CONSUMER Request: from 127.0.0.1:34080, method = POST, path = /consumers/my-group
[2020-11-24 11:46:09,508] INFO  <nsumerConfig:354> [oop-thread-1] ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = your-consumer
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = my-group
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

[2020-11-24 11:46:09,759] INFO  <ppInfoParser:117> [oop-thread-1] Kafka version: 2.6.0
[2020-11-24 11:46:09,759] INFO  <ppInfoParser:118> [oop-thread-1] Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
[2020-11-24 11:46:09,760] INFO  <ppInfoParser:119> [oop-thread-1] Kafka startTimeMs: 1606218369758
[2020-11-24 11:46:09,775] INFO  <idgeEndpoint:140> [oop-thread-1] Created consumer your-consumer in group my-group
[2020-11-24 11:46:09,781] INFO  <eateConsumer:85> [oop-thread-1] [9562016] CREATE_CONSUMER Response:  statusCode = 200, message = OK
[2020-11-24 11:46:33,188] INFO  <subscribe   :85> [oop-thread-1] [343058276] SUBSCRIBE Request: from 127.0.0.1:34370, method = POST, path = /consumers/my-group/instances/your-consumer/subscription
[2020-11-24 11:46:33,199] INFO  <idgeEndpoint:191> [oop-thread-1] Subscribe to topics [SinkTopicSubscription(topic=your-topic,partition=null,offset=null)]
[2020-11-24 11:46:33,224] INFO  <subscribe   :85> [oop-thread-1] [343058276] SUBSCRIBE Response:  statusCode = 200, message = OK
[2020-11-24 11:46:33,231] INFO  <afkaConsumer:965> [mer-thread-0] [Consumer clientId=your-consumer, groupId=my-group] Subscribed to topic(s): your-topic
[2020-11-24 11:46:58,713] INFO  <poll        :85> [oop-thread-1] [690326198] POLL Request: from 127.0.0.1:34814, method = GET, path = /consumers/my-group/instances/your-consumer/records
[2020-11-24 11:46:58,756] INFO  <poll        :85> [oop-thread-1] [690326198] POLL Response:  statusCode = 200, message = OK
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,358] INFO  <send        :85> [oop-thread-1] [859539310] SEND Request: from 127.0.0.1:35210, method = POST, path = /topics/your-topic
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,474] INFO  <oducerConfig:354> [oop-thread-1] ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.auto.downgrade.txn.commit = false
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

[2020-11-24 11:47:25,611] INFO  <ppInfoParser:117> [oop-thread-1] Kafka version: 2.6.0
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,631] INFO  <ppInfoParser:118> [oop-thread-1] Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,631] INFO  <ppInfoParser:119> [oop-thread-1] Kafka startTimeMs: 1606218445608
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,649] INFO  <oducerConfig:354> [oop-thread-1] ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 0
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-2
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.auto.downgrade.txn.commit = false
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

[2020-11-24 11:47:25,670] INFO  <ppInfoParser:117> [oop-thread-1] Kafka version: 2.6.0
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,671] INFO  <ppInfoParser:118> [oop-thread-1] Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,672] INFO  <ppInfoParser:119> [oop-thread-1] Kafka startTimeMs: 1606218445665
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,673] INFO  <Metadata    :279> [| producer-1] [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: MJQu4vwtR4iZ7eIiDp7zLg
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,685] INFO  <Metadata    :279> [| producer-2] [Producer clientId=producer-2] Cluster ID: MJQu4vwtR4iZ7eIiDp7zLg
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,714] INFO  <send        :85> [oop-thread-1] [859539310] SEND Response:  statusCode = 200, message = OK
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,938] INFO  <afkaProducer:1189> [ker-thread-7] [Producer clientId=producer-2] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
[2020-11-24 11:47:25,944] INFO  <afkaProducer:1189> [ker-thread-7] [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
[2020-11-24 11:47:41,679] INFO  <poll        :85> [oop-thread-1] [484189988] POLL Request: from 127.0.0.1:35416, method = GET, path = /consumers/my-group/instances/your-consumer/records
[2020-11-24 11:47:41,682] WARN  <etworkClient:1073> [mer-thread-0] [Consumer clientId=your-consumer, groupId=my-group] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {your-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
[2020-11-24 11:47:41,684] INFO  <Metadata    :279> [mer-thread-0] [Consumer clientId=your-consumer, groupId=my-group] Cluster ID: MJQu4vwtR4iZ7eIiDp7zLg
[2020-11-24 11:47:41,688] INFO  <poll        :85> [oop-thread-1] [484189988] POLL Response:  statusCode = 200, message = OK
[2020-11-24 11:53:01,882] INFO  <poll        :85> [oop-thread-1] [1610292326] POLL Request: from 127.0.0.1:39262, method = GET, path = /consumers/my-group/instances/your-consumer/records
[2020-11-24 11:53:01,883] INFO  <poll        :85> [oop-thread-1] [1610292326] POLL Response:  statusCode = 200, message = OK
[2020-11-24 11:53:01,946] INFO  <tCoordinator:815> [mer-thread-0] [Consumer clientId=your-consumer, groupId=my-group] Discovered group coordinator my-cluster-kafka-2.my-cluster-kafka-brokers.strimzi.svc:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
[2020-11-24 11:53:01,979] INFO  <tCoordinator:553> [mer-thread-0] [Consumer clientId=your-consumer, groupId=my-group] (Re-)joining group
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? If you want to list the topics, exec into the kafka pods, not the bridge

Comment: ok I get that ...but I want to see how kafka bridge work ...so just for understand that can I do something with my kafka bridge pods like I read some curl commands and all but i don't know how to do it....can you plz tell how can I run curl get ,post commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the `kafka-topics` tool from the bridge pod which doesn't include the Kafka binaries so there is no `kafka-topics` tool in there.
The command you are trying to execute can work on one of the Kafka pods you have deployed where the tool will be available.
Anyway, I don't understand the relation between what you are trying to achieve and the usage of bridge.
The bridge just provides an HTTP interface to Kafka on port 8080 so from within a pod in the Kubernetes cluster you can do GET/POST requests on the bridge endpoints for interacting with Kafka via HTTP.
The overall bridge documentation is available here: https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/
If you want to expose the bridge outside of the Kubernetes cluster then you can read more about it here: https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/11/05/exposing-http-bridge/
Finally a good bridge introduction is here: https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/07/19/http-bridge-intro/

Comment: Thanks your block really helped me a lot.

Comment: I followed the whole procedure given in your block ...but when I m trying to get all the messages I got only a "[ ]" ...I am not getting all the messages can you please tell me why I m having this issue.?

Comment: [strimzi@my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-bktc4 strimzi]$  curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/consumers/my-group/instances/your-consumer/records  H 'accept: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json'
[ ][strimzi@my-bridge-bridge-684df9fc64-bktc4 strimzi]$

Comment: are you doing a GET on the /records endpoint? empty means no records or it can happen the first time when the first GET on /records does actually do a poll for joining the consumer group, you should check if subsequent GET on /records still returns nothing while you are producing.

Comment: After producing the messages in the topic again I tried to get the messages but still I am getting nothing but [ ] only ...when I exec my kafka cluster pod and see the topic all the messages are there so I m little confused here why i M not getting records through curl command.

Comment: you should provide the exact info about the deployment and the curl commands you are running.

Comment: I edited my question you can see their I have mentioned everything.

Comment: Can you add the pod bridge log when running these commands please?

Answer (score 0):

Not entieraly sure about the Strimzi version, but to me it simply looks like the script is not in the $PATH or it is called a bit different. For example, this is from one of my clusters (I use Confluent's kafka helm chart though):

```
root@confluent-kafka-connect-6bf9c944f-fzbgc:/# which kafka-topics
/usr/bin/kafka-topics
root@confluent-kafka-connect-6bf9c944f-fzbgc:/# kafka-topics --help
This tool helps to create, delete, describe, or change a topic.
Option                                   Description         
------                                   -----------                            
--alter                                  Alter the number of partitions,        
                                           replica assignment, and/or           
                                           configuration for the topic.         
(...)
```

Comment: Thanks jordi-miralles ..but I am using strimzi and also new with kafka and strimzi so this is little confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka Bridge service is an HTTP service and doesn't have the Kafka CLI tools (and if it did, port 8080 would not respond to that command).

If you want to list topics, use a [GET /topics](https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/#_listtopics) request

You shouldn't need to exec into a container to do that, assuming you have an ingress or port forward to the bridge service

Comment: I just want to run any command with kafka bridge just to know how kafka bridge work ....my kafka cluster is running and my kafka bridge is also in running now plz lead me how and from where I can run curl commands ?....do I need to exec any pod or something ?

Comment: You can exec, or you expose the port outside of the cluster using an ingress service https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/. And you could use any http client, like postman, doesn't need to be curl